# Adding a UIToolBar Below UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to add a `ToolBar` beneath the `NavigationBar` in my `UITableViewController`. I have no clue how to do this programatically. Can someone please help me figure the code for this ?

A possible solution would be to make the class a `UIViewController` and then add a `tableview` controller to it. But if so, i am unable to add a `pulltoRefresh` feature to the `tableview`.

I think that there has to be a better approach than mine.

Comment: use a UIViewController subclass and change the pull-to-refresh code.

Comment: How to change the pullTorefresh code ? could show me an example

Comment: "pull to refresh" requires a UITableViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use UIViewController then add the UITableView as subview. More importantly you should pass the delegate and datasource to self, and adopt the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource.

```
[myTableView setDelegate:self];
[myTableView setDataSource:self];
```

> i am unable to add a pulltoRefresh feature to the tableview

How does pulltoRefresh works? If you mean reloadData, then probably you forget to connect the delegate and datasource for the tableview to work.